# How to get Key value if input data are event.code and current keyboard layout

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, keyboard, key, keyevent

I want to implement my own virtual keyboard which constructed in dynamic way.

I'd like to use event.code as key selector.

To make it supporting different system languages I need to prepare data maps where from I could take key-data: `event key value`, `event.location`, `event.which`.

Events that are real events accompanied by keystrokes.
Consider each of this you can using internet resources like [keycode.info](https://keycode.info/) or [mdn-doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values).

I do not have ones at time when my keyboard is under dynamic construction.

The idea is to avoid of using map per language layout. I'd like to know key value using `code name`, `location` and current layout.

for example:

```
keyboard layout | event.location | event.which | event.code | event.key
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       de       |       0        |      59     |  Semicolon |     ö
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       en       |       0        |      59     |  Semicolon |     ;
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       uk       |       0        |      59     |  Semicolon |     ж
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

considering table:

- `event.location` is order key number for each unique key;
- `event.which` is deprecated code to detect physical key on keyboard;
- `event.code` is a code to detect physical key on keyboard;
- `event.key` - value which I need depending on keyboard layout.

So we have a chances somehow to detect `key` if input data are `code` and `layout` for which we need the key.

Is there ideas how to get key not from event but from browser?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by "get key not from event but from browser"; can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks for comment, I've just added information to make it clear.